# jquery slide when pressing button

Tags: jquery, slide

I've made a [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LdJjs/7/) to explain my problem

What i want is to slide in the div newScreen while the div fullScreen is getting smaller. The actions runs by pressing **run**.

But as you can see the newScreen doensn't show.

Someone can tell me what to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Upvoted for making a fiddle. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) animations. To get your code working add the following references:

```
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui.jquery.com/latest/ui/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code ..

check [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/LdJjs/21/)

You forget to load the jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

To use the slide animation you need to include some elements of the jQuery UI... then your code works just fine :

http://fiddle.jshell.net/LdJjs/22/

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, there'll be a problem with the following line of code without JQueryUI reference.

```
$('#newScreen').show('slide',{direction: 'right'}, 1000);
```

So first thing you need to include the correct reference.

For the rest of your code, it's all good, but I personally would do something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#newScreen').hide();

    $('#addButton').click(function() 
    {
        $('#fullScreen').animate({"width":"50%"}, 1000, function() {
            $('#newScreen').show('slide',{direction: 'right'}, 1000);
        });
    }); 
});
```

And please check the JqueryUI reference in here as well: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Slide